# Doctrine difference make:migration et doctrine:migrations:diff

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I would have liked to know the difference between the `doctrine:migrations:diff` and `make:migration` commands for doctrine 2.2

A few months ago I was using `doctrine:migrations:diff` but in the Symfony documentation they now seem to favor `make:migration`

What's the difference between these two commands?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`make: migration` is just a wrapper for `doctrine:migrations:diff`. It's only change some output.

So it is better to use command from Symfony.

You can see the source code of `make:migration` here: https://github.com/symfony/maker-bundle/blob/v1.24.1/src/Maker/MakeMigration.php